# wamp icon is green but still getting an error "http 404"

Tags: wampserver, configure

I have changed the wamp server port from 80 to 81 and am having an error when trying to open localhost, error, http 404. what have I not done

Comment: Are you accessing http://localhost:81?

Answer (score 0):

Its best not to change the port number Apache uses, but if you do you then need change each address you use.

For example is you would have used localhost, you now need to use localhost:81

It s much easier to work out why port 80 will not work and fix that so you can stay on port 80